# Springboot application failing to create DB bean in Kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-data-jpa, amazon-ecs, amazon-eks

I have a springboot app that's perfectly running in ECS. When I migrate the deployment to EKS (Kubernetes), I am getting the following error:

`Error creating bean with name 'componentsHealthEndpoint': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dbHealthIndicator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: livenessStateHealthIndicator,readinessStateHealthIndicator,diskSpaceHealthIndicator`

I have defined my datasource URL, Password and Username in EKS configmap same in ECS. I also verified that I can connect to the DB from the EKS cluster by creating a pod and executing telnet from there.

I have also configured liveness and readiness probe in my EKS deployment.

`livenessProbe: httpGet: path: /actuator/health port: <PORT> initialDelaySeconds: 120 periodSeconds: 30 timeoutSeconds: 60 failureThreshold: 3 readinessProbe: httpGet: path: /actuator/health port: <PORT> successThreshold: 3 initialDelaySeconds: 120`

Don't know what else to check. What am I missing here?

Deployment should be fine same as ECS

Comment: Have you configured a Liveness or Readiness probe for your Pod? Is your application exposing a healthcheck URL? ECS doesn't have Liveness or Readiness probes so that could be reason for the discrepancy you're seeing.

Comment: @JeremyCowan I have configured liveness and readiness probe in my deployment. I just added it in the description. The path is the same health check path configured in ECS.

Comment: Hmm, it might be a Spingboot problem then.